# Looping through categories - displaying related image and title

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, categories

I've created an exhibition website for a client with categorised exhibitors (using Wordpress's baked in Post / Categories functionality) and using ACF I've created a related banner image for each category. (See the code for this below).

On another STATIC PAGE (slug named) "exhibitor-categories" I'd like to loop through all the categories the client creates, and display;

1. Each and every related associated thin banner category image,
2. With the appropriate (php single_cat_title();),
3. Wrapped in a (permalink) to this related category.

How Can I do this please?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
// Category Banner Image
$term = get_queried_object();
// Banner Image
$banner_image = get_field('midsummer_category_banner_image', $term); 
$banner_image_size = 'med-sm';   
$banner_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $banner_image, $banner_image_size );
$banner_image_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $banner_image, $banner_image_size ); 
$banner_image_alt_text = get_post_meta( $banner_image, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$banner_image_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $banner_image );
$banner_image_title = get_the_title( $banner_image );
?>
<!-- Main Page Content -->
<main>
    <!-- Category Banner -->
    <div class="category-banner">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $banner_image_src[0] ); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $banner_image_srcset ); ?>" sizes="100vw" alt="<?php echo $banner_image_alt_text ?>">
        <!-- Category Banner Title -->
        <div class="category-centered-banner-info">
            <h2><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Exhibitor Tiles -->
    <section>
            <div class="exhibitor-tiles">
                <div class="exhibitor-tiles-wrapper">
                    <!-- Exhibitors -->
                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                    <?php get_template_part('includes/category','exhibitors');?>
                    <?php endwhile; else: endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$banner_image = get_field('midsummer_category_banner_image', "category_".$term->ID);
```

Comment: thank you, I solved my issue before reading this but I think this way would have targeted the pictures too.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve what I was trying to achieve, so thought I'd post to potentially help others.

Heres the way I achieved it;

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories(); foreach ($categories as $category) {
?>
    // Category Banner Image
    $cat_banner_image = get_field('midsummer_category_banner_image', $category);   
    $cat_banner_image_size = 'med-sm';   
    $cat_banner_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_banner_image, $cat_banner_image_size );
    $cat_banner_image_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $cat_banner_image, $cat_banner_image_size ); 
    $cat_banner_image_alt_text = get_post_meta( $cat_banner_image, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $cat_banner_image_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $cat_banner_image );
    $cat_banner_image_title = get_the_title( $cat_banner_image );
?>
    <!-- Category Banner Buttons -->
    <a class="category-banner-button" href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/<?php echo $category->slug; ?>">
        <!-- Midsummer Category Banner Image -->
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $cat_banner_image_src[0] ); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat_banner_image_srcset ); ?>" sizes="100vw" alt="<?php echo $cat_banner_image_alt_text ?>">
        <!-- Category Title -->
        <h2 class="category-banner-button-title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
```